# JS function to remove element does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I got this code from here on the website and it works just fine on jsfidle ( http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tZPg4/4/ ) but when I put it on my website, the "remove" link does not do anything when I click on it.

Note: I already replaced "live" with "on".

Code:

**HTML:**

```
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
    </p>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

        $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
                $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;
                return false;
        });

        $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
});
```

Comment: You're giving a link to a jsfiddle which works, and the code you posted is exactly the same, means it works as well. How are we supposed to help you ? Try to reproduce what you've been doing in a fiddle and update your question.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @dcodesmith jquery-2.0.3

Comment: @FlorianF.   Exaclty it works on jsfiddle but when I copy paste it on the website only the first half of the function works(the one that adds the input fields), the other one does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change that `remScnt` into a `class`, since it will be present in the DOM more than once,

Just try the following,

```
$(document).on('click','.remScnt', function() { 
   if( i > 2 ) {
      $(this).parents('p').remove();
         i--;
      }
   return false;
});
```

Comment: @user3214754 Glad to help. Consider this as an accepted answer if you wish.

Comment: I assume that means click on the green check mark right? If so, with pleasure.